How to fully remove http-toolkit on windows
As the question states.  I did full uninstalls (including with Revo), deleted everything I could find in %appdata% directory, etc.
After re-install, all my rules were still there.
I manually deleted all rules, then did the uninstall procedure again.
On reinstall, the rules were gone, but all imported Trusted CA's still remained.
How to totally wipe out all http-toolkit configuration on the system?

Go to setting→ programs and features→ programs→ uninstall program.
Here, HTTP toolkit and choose it and uninstall it.
Now, all the remove configuration files on your desktop.
Going to the any folder path and delete all path and search here-> 'C\Users\Username\App\Data\Roaming\https-toolkit', then enter.
Here, username means your desktop name
Then delete the whole http-toolkit folder.
All clear here inside path.
Now, next to other phase→
Means remain all other files which is stored on the other location. How to search it?
You go to the your default drive and go to folder both program files one by one. And search http-toolkit. And then here all the remove also.
Registry is also clean. If you want all clean.
So, now window+R and type regedit and then enter.
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software
And HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE.but here to careful
Because if you delete other then your system has might problem.
Now. If here any file related this, also remove.
Now, after that. Restart your pc Or desktop. And they are confirmed clearly your desktop http toolkit remove.
